# Javascript switch within for-loop break; conflicts

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I have switch nested with loop in JavaScript like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxIds.length; i++) {
        if ($('#' + checkBoxIds[i]).prop('checked')) {
            var id = checkBoxIds[i];
            var assetCat = id.substring(0, 4);
            switch (id.substring(id.length - 3)) {
                case "scr":
                    if (!sscripts)
                        if (confirm("Name of scripts sub-folder (in shared) is not provided for " + assetCat + ". Press OK to Continue for others?"))
                            continue; else break; //else return
                    //Appending chrs or sets or props to scripts
                    switchAssets(sscripts, IdEnum.SCRIPTS);
                    break;
                case "shd":
                    if (!sshaders)
                        if (confirm("Name of shaders sub-folder (in shared) is not provided for " + assetCat + ". Press OK to Continue for others?"))
                            continue; else break; //else return
                    //Appending chrs or sets or props to shaders
                    switchAssets(sshaders, IdEnum.SHADERS);
                    break;
                case "sim":
                    if (!ssourceimages)
                        if (confirm("Name of sourceimages sub-folder (in shared) is not provided for " + assetCat + ". Press OK to Continue for others?"))
                            continue; else break; //else return
                    //Appending chrs or sets or props to sourceimages
                    switchAssets(ssourceimages, IdEnum.SOURCEIMAGES);
                    break;
                default:
            }
        }
    }

    //...Still doing something (else return; will never kiss this :D )
}
```

if *!sscripts* is falsy, i am asking user to if want to continue for other check-boxes, if he cancels, i want to break the loop and execute remaining statements within a function. Seems like break; within confirm dialog executing for switch, how can i make it to run for for-loop.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is exactly what [labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) are for:

```
theloop:
  for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxIds.length; i++) {
    ...

    switch (id.substring(id.length - 3)) {

      ...
        break theloop;
        // continue theloop;
```

Comment: Thanks, its working but is this a good practice? goto structures are never preferred constructs. Your link suggesting to use functions instead, can you elaborate on this please?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of this

```
 continue; else break; //else return
```

Try this

`continue; else break iWantHere;` //Break with label

Add this label `iWantHere` where you want your control to go

```
Example

 for(...)
 {
    switch('a')
    {
       case 'a': break iWantHere; // This will exit out of loop
       default:
    }
 }  

 iWantHere :
  // Rest of your code
```