# TypeScript break switch/case from nested for loop

Tags: javascript, typescript

Essentially, I am looking for the reverse of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821031/javascript-switch-within-for-loop-break-conflicts): if I have a for loop nested inside of a switch/case statement, is there a way to `break` out of the case? Trivial example:

```
switch (prompt('Left or right?')) {
  case 'left':
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      if (/* some condition */) {
        break case 'left' // this isn't valid
      }
    }
    break
  // ...
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Having a conditional nested in a loop nested in a switch seems like high time to write a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what labels were created for.  Apply the label to what you want to break out of and break the named block.  In this case, the named block is the switch statement:

```js
direction: switch (prompt('Left or right?')) {
  case 'left':
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      if (i==3) {
        break direction
      }
    }
    console.log('should not get here (remove "direction" above to test)')
    break
  default:
    break
}
```